# How to redirect to from /login to elsewhere if user is signed-in using React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

I have this:

```
  <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
    </Switch>
  </Router>
```

if the user goes to /login and the user is already logged-in I want to bounce them to their settings page.  Is there a way to do that declaratively with Router/Route, or do I need to call something like this within the Login component?

```
componentDidMount(){
   if(this.props.user){
     window.location.href = '/settings'
    }
}
```

what's the way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`<Redirect />`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect) and set [`to`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect/to-object) accordingly.

```
function AuthComponent(props) {
  const { user } = props;

  if (user.isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <Redirect to={{
        pathname: "/home",
        state: {
          from: location,
          user // user props
        }
      }} />
    );
  }

  return <Login />;
}

// PrivateRoute is an HOC injecting the user props.
<PrivateRoute exact path="/auth" component={AuthComponent} />
```

Comment: ok so that's within the render method of the Login component?

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman yes. or whatever component handling the authentication process.

Comment: Is there a way to put it in the router instead of the Login component?

Comment: @OlegzandrDenman well yes. But you would need to make use of `render` prop. See [this](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow) for more info.

Comment: got it thanks, I will try the `render` prop. if I do it the way you have it in your answer, how do I pass props to the Login component from the router?

Comment: Route props are automatically passed to the component via `<Route exact path="/somepath" component={AuthComponent} />`;